# Business logic wrapped inside a db transaction

Tags: database, design-patterns, transactions

In my app i have an api layer that defines routes, services layer to perform business logic, and a repository layer that queries the database. Services will call into the repository layer to retrieve data, perform various business logic and then return a response back to the api layer.

Now, I have some business logic that needs to be completed inside a database transaction. For example, let's assume my app allows you to buy tickets to a given event:

1. Service layer calls repository to atomically reserve tickets in the db by decrementing number of available tickets.
2. Service layer then makes an api request to process the payment for the ticket.
3. If the payment succeeds, service layer calls repository to create an "order" for the user and the given event.

If the payment fails, however, i want to rollback the changes made to the ticket availability. (or if for some reason creating the order for the user fails, same thing).

The problem is that it seems like a leaky abstraction if the services layer is aware of database transactions. Is there a better paradigm for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to hold a database transaction open the whole time you are making an API request anyway... You probably want to insert a 'pending' order, then once you get the payment change the status to 'confirmed'. This lets you store details about the error and report on failed payments too

Comment: Yeah thats another valid concern. However I see a couple issues with the solution you are proposing:
1. If the payment fails, how do we add the tickets back? The problem occurs if the server crashes for some reason after reserving the tickets, sending the payment request, which fails, and then crashes. 

2. If we have a pending order to mitigate issue 1, there are potentially race conditions, where by the time the order is confirmed tickets arent available anymore, and we charged the user

Comment: Reserve the tickets before calling the payment API - this is no different that holding a transaction, as other processes wouldn't be able to use them during that time anyway. When the system starts up, check for any 'pending' orders, double-check if the payment went through, then release the tickets or confirm the order

Comment: there's a potential race condition there:
order might be pending and payment not gone through just yet, we release the tickets, and then the payment goes through

Comment: yeah the payment api allows for idempotent requests. I suppose a valid solution would be to periodically clean up the database for any pending orders > x time ago. And then add those tickets back into the pool, and that can be done inside a transaction.